# map inserting keys but not value

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I am playing with c++ code today. Learning about std containers. I'm trying to insert and update data in a std::map but for some reason I can't insert values into a map. Keys will insert but not values. The code at the bottom will print the following if you enter something into the terminal that opens. In this example I entered "test". Anyway, my questions are, why is the insert returning false, why in the value not inserting?

```
test 
first 
failed 
Context1 :
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

static std::map<std::string, std::string> currentFullState;
static const std::string sDEFAULT_STRING = "";

void PringCurrentState()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator stateData = currentFullState.begin();
    while (stateData != currentFullState.end())
    {
        std::cout << stateData->first << " : ";
        std::cout << stateData->second << std::endl;
        stateData++;
    };
}
void UpdateState(std::string context, std::string data)
{
    if (currentFullState[context] == sDEFAULT_STRING)
    {
        // first entry, possibly special?
        std::cout << "first" << std::endl;
        auto result = currentFullState.insert(std::make_pair(context, data.c_str()));
        if (result.second == false)
            std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "good" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (data != currentFullState[context])
    {
        // change in value
    }
    else
    {
        currentFullState[context] == data;
    }
}
void DoWork()
{
    if (rand() % 2)
    {
        UpdateState("Context1", "Data1");
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateState("Context2", "Data2");
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::string command = "";
    for (;;)
    {
        PringCurrentState();

        std::cin >> command;
        DoWork();

        if (command == "q")
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the insert not work?

Comment: `if (currentFullState[context] == sDEFAULT_STRING)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly would help if you wrote

```
currentFullState[context] = data;
```

instead of

```
currentFullState[context] == data;
```

Also

```
auto result = currentFullState.insert(std::make_pair(context, data));
```

should be preferred to

```
auto result = currentFullState.insert(std::make_pair(context, data.c_str()));
```

Slightly surprised that the second one compiles.

=========================================================================

The real reason the insert fails is that you are adding that key for the second time. This is the first time

```
if (currentFullState[context] == sDEFAULT_STRING)
```

`operator[]` on a map *always* adds the key to the map. This is why your second attempt to add with

```
auto result = currentFullState.insert(std::make_pair(context, data.c_str()));
```

fails, the key is already present. If you had written

```
currentFullState[context] = data;
```

Then it would work.

Comment: Thanks for finding the typo! :)

Comment: @user1919249 ok, but it's not the real answer to your question, please see update.